# Mule http connector active threads keep remained in thread pool

Tags: multithreading, unix, mule, solaris, performance-testing

I use mule 2.2.1 with the following http incoming receiver configuration.

```
<http:connector name="abc.connector.http" >
    <receiver-threading-profile             maxThreadsActive="500"
            maxThreadsIdle="50"             threadTTL="60000"
            poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"          maxBufferSize="100"         />
</http:connector>
```

On production server, JVM frequently crashed. The JVM dump created as "hs_err_pid.log" is having threads like: `0x07990c00 JavaThread "ActiveMQ Session Task" [_thread_blocked, id=69807, stack(0x08770000,0x087b0000)]`.

There are around 2100 to 2300 threads in this crash every time.

My Question is:

1. Why it shows _thread_blocked?
2. When there is no load on Server, the count of threads are not reduced then 2000. Why it is so? I use **jstack -l PID** to check the no of running threads and **prstat | grep PID** to monitor the NLWP on solaris. It gives result like:

`17725 application_pprd 3409M 2593M sleep   59    0   0:10:51 0.1% **java/2375**`

3. How to remove this unused/inactive threads from pool to avoid crash?
4. How to increase this limit of NLWP for java process?

Comment: This sure seems like a [classic XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Your problem is the JVM crashing, not the number of threads it happens to be running when it crashes.  You actually have presented evidence of why the JVM is crashing, but it has nothing to do with the number of threads.  Look at the memory size - it's just short of 4 GB, which means it's running up against the limits of a 32-bit process.  Post entire output from a JVM crash, as well as the output from `pmap PID`, where PID is the process ID from a running JVM process.

Comment: Hello Andrew, thanks for the response. We are running with -d64 flag on JVM. It means JVM is running on 64 bit mode. So do you want me to increase the memory(heap xms and xmx param)? Because I reduced heap size from 2048 to 1536 and this NLWP was reaching to 2200.

Comment: pmap output : http://www.filedropper.com/pmap                      jvm crash: http://www.filedropper.com/hserrpid

Comment: @AndrewHenle do you need some more info?

Comment: That `pmap` output is from a 32-bit process.

Comment: Pls let me know the crosschecking process.

Comment: @AndrewHenle ohh. Then how to make this running on 64 bits?? How you crosschecked that its running in 32 bit mode??

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have made changes in params from -D64 to -d64.   24810 WBA_pprd 1923M 1671M sleep   59    0   0:01:42 9.7% java/1313

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am facing other issue here.. Now the permgen is reaching to 98% without any load on application. ** S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  0.00  41.47  15.44  83.77  98.56     23    2.613     0    0.000    2.613**

Comment: @AndrewHenle. You are right. Issue is resolved after making JVM 64 bit. Thanks a lot